# Caching ListFragment data

Tags: android, caching, android-fragments

My application generates ListFragments based on user type (determined by the DeviceID) and then fetch images from a web server. These images will then be displayed as a list.

My question is how can I cache those images as well as fragments (generated dynamically) to be displayed in offline mode. For instance when user opens the application without having an active internet connection, it should display the images within the fragments generated dynamically last time.

At the moment my app just download the images from a web service each time.

code for generating fragments dynamically in the MainActivity each time when the application loads.

```
    //generating the views based on JSON data
    try {
        JSONObject resultObject = new JSONObject(result.toString());
        boolean success = resultObject.getBoolean("success");
        JSONArray jArray = resultObject.getJSONArray("data");

        if (success == true) {
            //save menu 

            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                postObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                if (postObject.has("ev_count")) {
                    categoriesSet.put("Events", "Events");
                    mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Events"), EventsFragment.class, null);
                }

                if (postObject.has("pl_count")) {
                    categoriesSet.put("Places", "Places");
                    mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Places"), PlacesFragment.class, null);
                }

                if (postObject.has("gn_count")) {
                    categoriesSet.put("General", "General");
                    mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("General"), GeneralFragment.class, null);
                }
            }
        }

        //saving values to the shared preferences (hashmap as a string)
        categoriesPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = categoriesPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString("categories", categoriesSet.toString());
        editor.commit();

    }catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("ALLOCATE_DAT_ERROR", e.toString());
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide some code?
You are generating new Fragment classes or are you just creating new instances of some of yours Fragments?

Comment: @ simekadam I have provided the code that generates the fragments. Basically it generates new instances of the fragments

Answer (score 0):

I would just advice to use some image downloading library which also often handles caching for you..

**Here is a short list of some of them:**

[Volley](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/) - directly from google, its more like a whole networking stack, but it allows you to easily download Images (see `NetworkImageView`) and also to cache them (you need to provide a cache implemtantion - google will help you)

[Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) - nice library from square with very straightforward API - I would advice you to go with it, it might be the easiest way to go

[Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) - another option, it has really a lot of options and is also easy to use

Here is a simple sample code which should advice you how to use volley to load and cache images.

```
NetworkImageView mage = (NetworkImageView) view.findViewById(...);
image.setImageUrl("http://someurl.com/image.png",mImageLoader);
```

You need an `ImageLoader` instance then..

```
public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
    if (mImageLoader == null) {
        mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(getImageRequestQueue(), new DiskBitmapCache(getCacheDir(), 50 * 1024 * 1024));
    }
    return mImageLoader;
}
```

imageRequestQueue is standard queue you should have already initialised somewhere in your app if already using volley for networking stuff

As a DiskCache you can use [this](https://github.com/JakeWharton/DiskLruCache)

Comment: @ simekadam thanks, I am already using volley with LruCache, do you have any suggestions how to implement offline cache/disk cache using those two libraries. I mean which functions & etc to be called. I couldn't find a better example

Comment: Are you using disk cache, or just memory cache?

Comment: memory cache when getting images from the web service, i want them to be displayed in offline mode too. so i have to use disk cache right?

Comment: Thanks, is it possible for me to use key value pair when caching images to identify they are belonging to a particular fragment, so i can load them under a specific fragment when there is no internet connection

Comment: Volley uses image urls as keys..Are you able to persist those urls?
I don't see how to even if are you saving the downloaded JSON..
Also..where are your fragments getting its data from?

Comment: I am creating objects (like events places & etc) in my app, within those objects I have the image URL (fetch from the JSON response/array). Is that what you mean?

Comment: Well then you need to persist those objects..
You can serialize them to disk, you can save the original JSON to disk, or you can design a database and save your data there..

Comment: that sounds great..so can images be serialised to make them smaller in size? I mean if i serialise an object will it save the images as well?

Comment: no..dont serialise those images..serialize just the object with the url..and then query volley with the url..and it will automatically populate the cached version if present..